# Passing argument to an Action without using an anonymous function?

Tags: c#

Is there a way I can pass through an argument to an Action without using an anonymous function?

Eg, the following code works fine:

```
private void doSomethingAndLogIt(string log, Action dosomething)
{
        Debug.WriteLine(log);
        dosomething();
}

private void multiplyIt()
{
        _result = "great";
}

...

doSomethingAndLogIt("Did something", multiplyIt);
```

but what I want to do is this:

```
private void doSomethingAndLogIt(string log, Action<int> dosomething)
{
        Debug.WriteLine(log);
        dosomething(???);
}

private void multiplyIt(int a)
{
        _result = "great";
}

doSomethingAndLogIt("Did something", multiplyIt(5));
```

I realise that I can do this:

```
private void doSomethingAndLogIt(string log, Action<int> dosomething, int inputValue)
{
        Debug.WriteLine(log);
        dosomething(inputValue);
}

private void multiplyIt(int a)
{
        _result = "great";
}

doSomethingAndLogIt("Did something", multiplyIt, 5);
```

but it's pretty confusing. I also realise that I can do this:

```
doSomethingAndLogIt("Did something", () => {
    multiplyIt(5);
});
```

but it would be great if I could do this:

```
doSomethingAndLogIt("Did something", multiplyIt(5));
```

Comment: Not really clear what you're asking or trying to achieve here. You have code that works, what is missing?

Comment: @juharr That's the second last code in the question

Comment: While the same as your last example you can do `() => multiplyIt(5)` without the body, which is close to what you want.

Comment: @juharr thanks, that's pretty helpful, it would still be nice to be able to remove the () => alltogether though.

Comment: @DavidG can you please read the question properly? I explained pretty clearly what I'm trying to do. Even though it's working, I want it to be neater and simpler and don't know how to do what I want to do, or if it's possible or not.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to do anything special. This code below:

```
doSomethingAndLogIt("Test", () => multiplyIt(5));
```

will already do what you are after. When the delegate is called, the parameter `5` will be passed in as well. Why? Because the callee will call your delegate, and you will call the method `multiply` with the argument `5`.

[Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sfX9rQ) is a quick test.

Comment: You haven't understood my question. I understand that this will work but I'm trying to understand why I need the anonymous function at all.

Comment: @rocklan Because if you remove the `() =>`, then it will just call the method `multiplyIt(5)` and send the return of that as the 2nd argument to `doSomethingAndLogIt`. Thats how C# (and many other languages) work.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to do that as of the current version of C#, here's why...

Let's take your example (fake syntax)

```
public int MultiplyIt(int value)
{
    //Do something that has side-effects
}

public void SomeMethod(Action<int> someAction<int>)
{
    //Do something
    someAction();
}
```

Now let's create an override of that method:

```
public void SomeMethod(int someValue)
{
    //Do something
}
```

Now you call it:

```
SomeMethod(multiplyIt(5))
```

Which one does the compiler call?

Lets say you don't overload it (or that for some reason the compiler shouts an error if you do, but it is legal).

What then is the difference between these two calls?

```
SomeMethod(multiplyIt(5));
SomeMethod(() => multiplyIt(5));
```

Technically the first one runs `multiplyIt` *before* passing its value to `SomeMethod`. The second one `multiplyIt` may never be called, or it may alter something and then call it. That is an important distinction. If you add in some method to call it without the `() =>` part, the developer can't know, without reading documentation, how the method call (and the action) are called. Is it a normal method call? The "special" delegate case? Who knows.

The `() =>` isn't that much of a price to pay to be able to read a method and understand that you are passing in a delegate vs a value.

Comment: Ahh!! Thanks very much ! The function would be called _before_ passing the value.. that makes sense now. Great explanation.